# How to run 'main' in parallel in Pycharm?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pycharm

I want to run my 'main.py' file with a certain hard-coded variable, then change the variable and run it again simultaneously. The code takes a while to run, so I want them to be parallel.

I've tried going into the 'Run Configurations' menu and ticking allow parallel run, but it doesn't do anything. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: You can open several python consoles and terminals in parallel in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a Run Config for each of the different ways you want to run main.py and then use a Compound run config to run all of the separate run configs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another script where you use `subprocess.Popen(["python", "C:/filepath/main.py", "arg1", "arg2"], shell=True)` to run a command on the terminal, the command in this case looks like `python C:/filepath/main.py arg1 arg2`. Here, you are passing arguments to the script, that you can access by using `import sys` and `sys.argv[1]` in your `main.py` python script. `sys.argv[1]` would give you `arg1` in this case.

By having two of these subprocesses, you start running them in parallell. Example:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(["python", "C:/filepath/main.py", "first_argument"], shell=True)
b = subprocess.Popen(["python", "C:/filepath/main.py", "second_argument"], shell=True)

a.wait()
b.wait()
```

The `wait()` will keep the script running until both of the subprocesses are done.

Lookup `https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html` for more information.